# cannot display or retrieve the file in the view, which is uploaded in database in the form of path. (using laravel )

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have uploaded the path of files(multimedia files) in database and now i am having hard time retrieving it to the 'view'. example the files get uploaded but cannot be viewed or played.

I have tried multiple ways of handling it but none works.

**this is my balde**

```
<div>     
  @foreach ($users as $user)                          
    Title: {{ $user->title }}  <br>                       
    By: {{ $user->author }}  <br>
    <audio src="{{ url('audios/') }}" controls>
    </audio> <br><br><br>               
  @endforeach
</div>
```

**and controller**

```
     $audio = $request->file('audio-folktale');

     $new_name = $audio->getClientOriginalName();

     $location = $audio->move(public_path('audios'), $new_name);

       $request->validate([

          'title' => 'required:max:25',
          'author' => 'required'

       ]);

       auth()->user()->audios()->create([
           'title' => $request->get('title'),
           'author' => $request->get('author'),
           'audio' => $request->get('audio',$location)

       ]);

       return redirect()->route('viewAudio');
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using `$user->audio`? `src="{{ url('audios/') }}"` points to a path

Comment: this point to my public folder,in there i have folder called audios

Comment: please help me i have been stuck for a while now

Answer (score 0):

Your view file like this:

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)                          

                     Title: {{ $user->title }}  <br>                       

                     By: {{ $user->author }}  <br>

                      <audio src="{{ url('audios/') }}{{$user->audio}}" controls>

                      </audio> <br><br><br>               
                       @endforeach
```

Comment: it gives no error and my audio can't be played either

Comment: it had happened such that i tried to give location to the database, if not just by name it was functioning well. but i need to upload location in db.